# Why do inherited Docker images differ in size

Tags: docker

I'm lately experimenting with Docker. I try to build an image architecture looking like this for easy maintenance and extensibility.

[image: architecture]

I built images with following Dockerfiles and am curious about different container sizes. Why do they differ this much?

Following **base/Dockerfile** results in a **210.9 MB** image (ubuntu:trusty having 188 MB so that's okay).

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install \
    nano
ENV TERM xterm
RUN apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

**apache/Dockerfile** results in **224.4 MB**.

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install \
    nano \
    apache2
ENV TERM xterm
RUN apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
COPY apache2-foreground /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /var/www/html
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

**apache-php/Dockerfile** results in **266.7 MB**.

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install \
    nano curl \
    apache2 \
    libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-mcrypt php5-gd php5-curl php-pear php-apc && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN /usr/sbin/php5enmod mcrypt
# + last 7 lines from apache/Dockerfile
```

That's fine so far but we haven't used inheritance until now. Let's have a look:

Why does **apache-php-on-base/Dockerfile** result in **289.4 MB**? It's basically the same steps but split in two images. I would have expected a little overhead but not about 10 %.

```
FROM base
# + apache-php/Dockerfile without "install nano"
```

It's even bigger using multiple inheritance: **apache-php-on-apache-on-base/Dockerfile** results in **314.9 MB**.

```
FROM apache-on-base
# + apache-php/Dockerfile without "install nano apache2"
```

Where **apache-on-base/Dockerfile** is of course (resulting in **247 MB**):

```
FROM base
# + apache/Dockerfile without "install nano"
```

**Question:** Is there a way preventing images from growing this large while preserving maintainability?

**Update:** Implementing thaJeztah's suggestions I got following :) Thanks again!

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
apache-php-on-aob   latest              2cf12a3b5872        2 minutes ago       249.9 MB
apache-on-base      latest              121c8a098ff5        3 minutes ago       203.7 MB
base                latest              ee95e4f8aaee        3 minutes ago       189.3 MB
apache-php-on-aob   v1                  e43df5e61aed        3 days ago          314.9 MB
apache-on-base      v1                  c291f91f1a10        3 days ago          247 MB
base                v1                  b181fc6f181d        3 days ago          210.9 MB
ubuntu              trusty              97434d46f197        10 days ago         188 MB
```

Comment: Try running `docker history <image ID>` on your images and you can see which layers are bigger / smaller between the images to pinpoint where the extra bloat comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going through all differences in depth, the most likely reason is that
you're not taking the layered filesystem into account.

Docker creates a *new* imagelayer for each instruction in your Dockerfile. Basically
what happens is (very much simplified):

So, this will become the first layer:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
```

(And Docker does something like)

```
Docker build -t layer1 .
```

This will become the second layer:

```
FROM layer1
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install \
    nano
```

(And Docker does something like)

```
Docker build -t layer2 .
```

And so on.

The final image is a combination of all those images "stacked". The important thing
to realize there is that a file that's added in "layer1", but *removed* in "layer2"
is still part of the image; Docker only marks it as "removed" in layer2, but that
doesn't make the image smaller.

Let's have a look at your first Dockerfile. As you can see you're *adding* a lot
of files in the first `RUN` instruction, then add an empty layer that only sets
an `ENV` var, followed by another `RUN` that removes all the redundant files
from the first `RUN`. However, those files aren't removed from the earlier layer,
so still take up space in the final image;

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install \
    nano
ENV TERM xterm
RUN apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

After building (`docker build -t foobar .`), this gives me:

```
REPOSITORY  TAG      IMAGE ID      CREATED        SIZE
foobar      latest   363aa5572838  2 minutes ago  210.9 MB
```

Making a small change, and combine the two `RUN` instructions, so that both the
`apt-get update` and `apt-get clean` steps take place in the *same* `RUN`, so 
the *same* layer;

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install \
    nano && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
ENV TERM xterm
```

And building that, produces this image:

```
REPOSITORY  TAG      IMAGE ID      CREATED        SIZE
foobar      latest   ac8fb5e4db16  9 minutes ago  189.3 MB
```

That's 20MB smaller!

You can read more about this in the [Dockerfile best practice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)
section of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! That really helps me understanding what's going on :)