# Docker Gradle project generates single JAR, but keeps rebuilding 4 layers

Tags: java, gradle, docker

Using Docker 1.12. For some reason, when I build my Docker container which is a Gradle 2.14 project, it builds the fat JAR and stores it locally. The problem is that although I have a single fat JAR being stored in the Docker image, it creates 4 new layers each around 300MB.

Not sure why it requires so much space for a single file. How can I optimize this Dockerfile to prevent it in the future?

Should I be building the JAR outside the container and then copying it?

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8_jdk

WORKDIR /

RUN mkdir /build

COPY . /build

WORKDIR /build

RUN mkdir /app
RUN cp ./lib/machine-learning-models.jar /app/machine-learning-models.jar

RUN bash gradlew shadowJar
RUN cp ./build/libs/server-0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar /app/server.jar

WORKDIR /
RUN rm -rf /build

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT java -cp /app/machine-learning-models.jar:/app/server.jar com.company.Boot
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the best solution is to just build the fat JAR outside the container and `COPY` it.

My final solution uses a bare bones Docker Alpine container bundled with the Java JRE. At build time I run `gradle shadowJar` and then copy the JAR into the container.

`FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8_jre`

As per @mixja's response, it's essentially a "release" image.

Answer (score 0):

Docker creates a new layer for each command in the Dockerfile. So to prevent Docker from doing this you could aggregate your RUN-commands like this:

```
[...]
WORKDIR /build

RUN mkdir /app \
    && cp ./lib/machine-learning-models.jar /app/machine-learning-models.jar \
    && bash gradlew shadowJar \
    && cp ./build/libs/server-0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar /app/server.jar

WORKDIR /
[...]
```

Notice the `\` at the end of each line for masking line break.

This way Docker only creates one layer for the RUN-command and doesn't need that much disk space. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273534/5777603) for details.

Comment: Interesting, why would the disk space increase so significantly if the JAR files are separated in two different commands? (the underlying cause)

Answer (score 0):

You should build the JAR separately (either externally or in a different build image/container copying out to local FS) and then copy the JAR file in to a "release" image (which now only needs the JRE not JDK) as a single operation.